# Site to Site VPN with ISA 2006 to a Dyndns Hostname?

Tags: vpn, hostname, isa-server

I would like to create a site-to-site VPN between my ISA 2006 and a DLink router on the other side.

My ISA got a fixed external IP Address, but the Dlink only has a dynamic one. So it makes use of DynDNS.

Every "cheap router" supports making VPNs to a hostname, but in ISA 2006 I have to enter a IP Address in the VPN settings.

Is there any way to create the VPN connection to a Hostname?

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that the problem is the TCP/IP stack of Windows Server 2003.
According to that, it is not possible to create a VPN to a DYNDNS Host.

Wasn't able yet to try that on Windows Server 2008 and TMG.

Kind regards,
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you cannot enter the dns address where it says ip address?

Comment: The reason is the textbox of the ISA Server Wizard. I cannot enter  a DNS name ;(

kind regards

Comment: Using a hostname / dyndns entry is considered insecure, the ISAKMP passphrase is tied to the remote IP in most VPN devices. Also you'd need fully functional PTR records to validate the remote entry when the tunnel comes up, as the remote peer (ISA) can't see the A record on an incoming tunnel connection.